Configure React to make HTTPS requests through frontend IP instead of client IP
I'm trying to secure an application, deployed in Azure, consisting of a React frontend and a Python backend. I want the frontend to be accessible via the internet unlike the backend which should only be accessible from the frontend (without being accessible via the internet). The backend seems to restrict access by taking the client's IP instead of the frontend's IP which causes a 403 IP Forbidden error.
To do this, I created:

1 App Service for the frontend
1 App Service for the backend, which allows access from within the virtual network
1 Virtual Network:

1 Subnet for 1 private endpoint, which the backend is attached to
1 Subnet for the frontend App Service



My boss recommends just switching to Next.js, but that would take 2-3 weeks, and I am not even sure if that would fix the issue. I believe this has to be easier, there is just something I am missing.

Seems to me like a case for server-side rendering using something like a Blazor Web App. If you're going to be using a client-side rendered frontend, it will always be the client's browser performing the requests to the backend service, which makes restricting access complicated -- if not impossible.

Okay. Thank you!


Configure React to make HTTPS requests through frontend IP instead of client IP

You restrict access to backend APIs to trusted sources by integrating a vnet with App Service.
Firstly create VNet and Integrate App Service with a VNet by while using Private end point Enabling VNet integration for Azure App Service.

and now connect the app service using the same vnet that used for webapp integration using same vnet

Inorder to establish the connection from frontend to backend app you should create the backend private endpoint and frontend appication using vnet integartion using same vnet so that you will be able to make the communication from front end to backend
if you want to send the traffic by public IP you can create a natgateway by attaching it to the frontend subnet.
Refer:
Enable Azure Private Link back-end and front-end connections - Azure Databricks | Microsoft Learn
How to Set Up Access Control Between Azure Static Web Apps and Azure App Service? - Stack Overflow

Thank you for the detailed response! I have set up the vnet, however the backend receives the client IP, therefore putting the frontend and backend into the vnet does not seem to help. I will try to use a gateway in front of the backend. I blieve that should help. This is my first time with Azure Portal, but I hope it works out.
